# how to add ADD TO CART button in catalog search

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, magento-2.1, php

I want ADD TO CART button in [search entire store] search box, when we are searching for any product. I am getting only name and price when i am searching for a product, i want add to cart button with those . How can I do that, which files are responsible for that functionality.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In to your `custom block` file you need to added this code.

```
<?php

protected $listProductBlock;

public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $listProductBlock) 
{
        $this->listProductBlock = $listProductBlock;
}

public function getAddToCartPostParams($product)
{
    return $this->listProductBlock->getAddToCartPostParams($product);
}
```

Now in your `phtml file` on top added this one :

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
```

inside product collection you need to added code like this one :

```
<?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>

<form data-role="tocart-form" data-product-sku="<?= $escaper->escapeHtml($_product->getSku()) ?>"
   action="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($postParams['action']) ?>" method="post">
       <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
       <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED ?>" value="<?php echo $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]; ?>">

      <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
      <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Cart')) ?>" class="action tocart primary" disabled>
           <span><?php echo $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span>
      </button>
</form>
```

For More Information you can check default list file :

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml